# React JS adding Multi Drag

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm working with [@hello-pangea/dnd](https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd) and I have this code: [vertical list with multiple drop targets](https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-list-with-multiple-drop-targets-5hc7wr?file=/index.js)

so, I want to add multi drag like this example [Multi drag](https://dnd.hellopangea.com/?path=/docs/examples-multi-drag--pattern) when I clicked on one item and press key `ctrl` simultaneously, the items is selected and I can drag and drop multiple items, what can I added for add select multiple items???